# Hiding AppBarLayout and giving its space to the remaining view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a pretty standard layout using the new design libraries:

```
<AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <Toolbar/>
    </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView/> <!-- content here -->
```

What I'm trying to do is to completely hide the whole `AppBarLayout` programmatically, to temporarily get rid of the `Toolbar` and its collapsing feature.

So I'm calling this:

```
private void disableCollapsing() {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    p.setScrollFlags(0);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
}
```

to disable the collapsing behavior (works well), and finally this:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    final AppBarLayout layout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);

    layout.animate().translationY(-layout.getHeight())
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }).start();
}
```

I make the AppBarLayout translate to the top (works smoothly), and at the end of the animation set is visibility to `View.GONE`.

### Issue

At the end of the animation, no matter I also set the visibility to GONE, I can't get the space that was previously occupied by the `AppBarLayout`. My NestedScrollView remains confined in the lower half of the screen, as if the AppBarLayout was still there (which is not). How can I fix it?

Before hiding:

[image: Before]

After hiding (AppBar translated to the top):

[image: After]

As you can see, the top space is empty and unreachable. The scroll view scrolls inside the margins it had before, as if the visibility change was not measured by the `CoordinatorLayout`.

- I have tried calling `coordinator.requestLayout()`, with no success.
- I also tried setting the AppBarLayout as an `app:anchor` for my NestedScrollView, but that screws things up - scroll view ends up taking the whole screen even before hiding.
- I was thinking of a custom `Behavior` to be set on the scroll view when entering this *hidden-AppBar mode*, but I can't get started on that.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this. I got the same issue, This issue can be reproduced as well in Chris Bane's cheesesquare in the Chesse detail screen remove two Textview from layout the issue will reproduce.

Comment: @AftabAli check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785550/collapsingtoolbar-not-working-with-not-so-tall-content) and see if it helps.

Comment: Check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364425/how-to-hide-show-widget-appbarlayout-on-click-in-android-app/73741324#73741324

Answer (score 27):

Yes this looks like a bug, I solved this issue for my application setting the appbar height to 0:

```
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout appbar = (android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();

lp.height = 0;

appbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I was setting visibility gone and also height 0. Using only height 0 is the right solution.

Comment: wonderful solution. i'm intreigued how getting a hold of lp can allow you to adjust the height, in my case (hide it) by setting the value to 0. something that i foudn to be useful was the case (show it) by doing a simple, `lp.height = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;` or whatever your desired height is for your layout (assuming coordinator layout).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, setting the `Coordinator.LayoutParams#height` fixes the issue.

However, I wanted to express how/when this occurs (not necessarily why):

The `CollaspingToolbarLayout` will exhibit this behavior only when its `app:layout_scrollFlags` property is set to `exitUntilCollapsed` and its nested `ToolBar` also has defines `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`. With this combination of flags, the `Toolbar` will pin itself to the top of the screen, and this is intentional and sometimes desirable.

(snipped for brevity)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!-- some other component here, i.e ImageView -->

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- some scrolling view/layout -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the Fragment/Activity after the view is created, in Kotlin + ViewBinding:

```
binding.appbar.updateLayoutParams<CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams> {
    height = 0
}
```

For me, I had to capture the height of the `AppBarLayout` before hiding it to restore it to its original height when I wanted to show it.

```
private var appbarLayoutHeight = 0
private fun hideAppBar() {
    appbarLayoutHeight = binding.appbar.measuredHeight
    binding.appbar.updateLayoutParams<CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams> {
        height = 0
    }
}
private fun showAppBar() {
    binding.appbar.updateLayoutParams<CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams> {
        height = appbarLayoutHeight
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: `ViewBinding` is not necessary to achieve this, nor is using Kotlin, and it's just what I use to acquire the `AppBarLayoout` and make this as terse/sugary as possible.*

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just toggles appbar on/off.

```
private boolean hide = true;
public void toggleAppBar() {

    // Calculate ActionBar height
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = hide ? 0 : actionBarHeight;
    appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(!hide, true);

    hide = !hide;
```

appbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Caleb Kleveter that is my code for Kotlin

```
    val appBarLayout = activity?.findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.app_bar_layout)
    val lp = appBarLayout?.layoutParams
    lp?.height = 0;
    appBarLayout?.layoutParams = lp
```

Answer (score -2):

The following works as well

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);
appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: when did this become available? doesn't seem to work in com.android.support:design:22.2.1

Comment: this code doesn't work. when scroll down, it shows again appbarlayout empty

Comment: this is does not work. Did  You try this on practic before posted?