# how to hide/show widget.AppBarLayout on click in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have developed an application and my requirement is to show setting button at the top on click.

Below is the code for my Activity_main.xml,

Any shortcut way to auto hide and show the app bar layout?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Following is the code at main_activity.java for onclick logic:

```
        final AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarlayout);
    appbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            appbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Thanks

[image: example]

in the screen shot you can see the setting button, I want to hide this whole blue color appbar.

Comment: can you show us what you mean by "setting menu"?

Comment: Dear @roarster I have added a screen shot. I want to auto hide/show of this blue appbar on click on screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use View's [`setVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) to hide and show the `AppBarLayout`.

If you want it to animate then add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the AppBarLayout's xml.

Comment: I have added the android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to my appbarLayouts xml
But still the layout do not animate.

   '<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">'

Comment: does it just instantly disappear when you call `setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: where should I call the setVisibility(view.gone)
In main_activity?

    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

like this?

Comment: In the listener that responds to your click (you mentioned you wanted it to hide when you click). You'll need to give your `AppBarLayout` an id in xml so that you can reference it from inside your `Activity` using `findViewById()`.

Comment: Dear @roarster, I have added the logic for findViewById()

But now the whole screen become blank white.
Any suggestions?

you can see the questions for updated code as well

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Scrolling Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html) of a child View.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Then add the scrollFlags of your Toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

And finally, simulate a scroll every N seconds so the Toolbar gets hidden.

```
//After 5 secs, scroll screen to N item in a list or something.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these, still not working.  better solution is show and hide the CollapsingToolbar  and set the AppBarLayout params dynamically.

Do this when ever you show/hide the **CollapsingToolbarLayout**

```
mAppBar.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```