# NestedScrollView cut/overlay bottom of nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have problem with `NestedScrollView`, because it cuts bottom of view.

I have `FragmentA` with schema:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <ImageView/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout> 
                <!-- fragment added dynamically-->
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout>
                <!-- fragment added dynamically-->
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout>
                <!-- fragment added dynamically-->
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am adding dinamically fragments to each `FrameLayout`.

I did SS how it look like when I run app first time: [Screen at first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqSwW.png)
I put padding to every layout to see what is happend.
`green` is `CoordinatorLayout`,
`red` is `NestedScrollView`,
`orange`is `LinearLayout` inside `NestedScrollView`.

Now I am replace `FragmentA` with `FragmentB` and again comeback to `FragmentA` and I have something like this: [wrong dispaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axgLn.png)

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

This is my whole layout for `FragmentA`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorP"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/przyciski">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="25dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="descp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorRedCalendar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameForInfo"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameForCalendar"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameForGraph"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/floatingButtonLog" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
I compile with:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
}
```

I am adding `Fragments` into `FrameLayout` with:

```
infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
    infoFragment.setLogs(mapLogIn, mapLogOut, monthToDispaly, yearToDispaly);
    infoFragment.setPracownik(mPracownik);


    if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("INFO") == null) {
        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frameForInfo, infoFragment, "INFO")
                .commit();
    }else {
        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameForInfo, infoFragment, "INFO")
                .commit();
    }
```

How I replacing `FragmentA` with `FragmentB`:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frameForFragment, edit)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

And how I come back from `FragmentB` to `FragmentA`:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(AddingPerson.this).commit();

                    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }
```

It looks like NestedScrollView was cuted at the bottom, because (if you look at ss) there is no padding frame at bottom.

I notice that when I come back to `FragmentA` (when wrong display is dispalying) and I replace fragments inside `NestedScrollView` bottom of `NestedScrollView` appears.

[Here is YT video.](https://youtu.be/01HFusR7lWg)

**UPDATE**

I found temporary answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612310/android-nestedscrollview-has-wrong-size-after-applayout-behavior). I added:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

But there is written that this bug is fixed in v22.2.1 but it seems is not. Somebody knows something about that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

in your NestedScrollView

Comment: Yes, I did it and it helped, but I am still unsatisfied, because it should play without this.

Comment: It helped you in the way you wanted? If yes, then why are you dissatisfied?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your nestedscrollview

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: I did it.  Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer add a margin when rotating the screen or the when the soft keyboard was displayed. I fixed by adding an OnGlobalLayoutListener() to the main view, and calling a requestLayout() to such view from inside the listener.